# Creating a public app in shopify using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, shopify, codeigniter-3, shopify-app

I am new to shopify, I want to create a public app which can communicate with store.
I have created a shopify partner account, an app and setup a Codeigniter project. Also added app url using ngrok.
Can anyone guide me with what should be the next step?

Comment: You can leverage this repo to start with the shopify app https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify

Answer (score 0):

When you say public app I believe that you want to set a view or functionality available to your customers, and that will communicate with your store. Let's say your store is:

https://mystore.myshopify.com

Your App should consider an URL for backend and frontend. Probably the App that you have now is the backend and will be embedded in your Admin Dashboard after you have installed. By now, I'm assuming that you got it done.

**Backend:** https://4b67b991.ngrok.io/backend

**Frontend:** https://4b67b991.ngrok.io/frontend

The App you created should have the scope "Online Store" so that you can set up a Proxy App.

Once you set up a Proxy app, with let's say:

**Sub path prefix:** apps

**Subpath:** myapp

**Proxy URL:** https://4b67b991.ngrok.io/frontend

Now, when you go to: https://mystore.myshopify.com/apps/myapp, the proxy URL will be embedded in your store using the header and footer of your theme and in the middle area, you can create your custom functionality using the Shopify API.

Before your app can be embedded in the frontend (with header and footer), you should change the content type of your document. In Laravel I use the following code:

```
    $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/liquid');
```

Your question is quite general and I'm 100% sure about what you want to achieve, but I believe that it's a starting point.